# Cuda 2.1 Help (Fedora 8 Werewolf)

Tags: cuda, fedora

I'm trying to write a kernel function to speed up some simulation programs I have. However, the server I'm running on is currently running Cuda 2.1 on Fedora 8, and I cannot seem to find any Cuda 2.1 documentation or programming guides. Does anyone know where I can find Cuda 2.1 programming guides?

Thanks in advance!

Dylan

Comment: This can be found on the first page of google results for (Nividia cuda Reference Manual version 2) http://www.cs.ucla.edu/~palsberg/course/cs239/papers/CudaReferenceManual_2.0.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Every CUDA toolkit back to 2.2 can be found on the NVIDIA CUDA archive [page](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-toolkit-archive).

If you grab an installer for cuda 2.2 and run it in a private directory, you can extract the documentation from it.

You may also find the programming guide in a doc directory under the cuda install on your server.

And as indicated already in the comments, you can google around for it on the web.  For example the 2.2 guide is [here](http://www.math.oregonstate.edu/~mpesz/code/cuda/NVIDIA_CUDA_Programming_Guide_2.2.1.pdf)

The 2.1 programming guide is [here](http://www.umiacs.umd.edu/~ramani/cmsc828e_gpusci/CUDA21.pdf)

And suggest to whoever is running that setup to upgrade to a more recent version of CUDA.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback and for the programming guide! It'll make things so much easier.